# Genymotion doesn't show anything and has white screen at launch

Tags: genymotion

Installed Genymotion and it shows this screen at the launch, not even able to see the virtual devices. 
Operating system is Windows 7, 64 bit and has latest drivers installed. Virtualization is enabled. Re-installed the latest version of genymotion and virtual box couple of times but no help.

Windows Application logs shows "Faulting application name:genymotion.exe,version 0.0.0.0
Faulting module name: Qt5Core.dll, version 5.9.6.0"

Genymotion logs

[Genymotion:3488] [debug] GL_VERSION: "OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.8613f4946861)"
[Genymotion:3488] [debug] GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: "OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.8613f4946861)"
[Genymotion:3488] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostinfo")
[Genymotion:3488] [warning] QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

[Genymotion:3488] [warning] shader compilation failed: 
"Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
[Genymotion:3488] [warning] QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.

[Genymotion:3488] [warning] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
[Genymotion:3488] [warning] QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

[image: White screen genymotion]

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that your Graphics device and/or display drivers do not handle OpenGL 2.0 correctly.
See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002732678-Virtual-device-display-is-black-in-Genymotion-Desktop